# How to enable and check status of guard pages in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

> G
>       “Guard”. Enable guard pages. Each page size or larger allocation is followed by a guard page that will cause a segmentation fault upon
>   any access

How can I enable guard pages to harden an OpenBSD install?

Also, how can I check what is the current status of the malloc settings?

In http://man.openbsd.org/malloc.conf.5 I can see:

Set a systemwide reduction of the cache to a quarter of the default size and use guard pages:

```
# ln -s 'G<<' /etc/malloc.conf
```

This probably enabled guard pages, but what is the "<<" and the "reduction of the cache to a quarter of the default size".

I just want to enable guard pages, afaik that is the most secure setting for malloc.conf.

Comment: Years ago, this was done by a library called ElectricFence by Bruce Perens that you could use as a replacement malloc on any system with mmap. It had run-time options never to free a page, and to align allocations with the end of a page rather than beginning to better detect overruns versus underruns

Comment: update: there is no way, maybe write own code to check :)

Answer (score 2):

Excerpts from the man page which you link:

```
 G       ``Guard''.  Enable guard pages.  Each page size or larger
         allocation is followed by a guard page that will cause a
         segmentation fault upon any access.

 <       ``Half the cache size''.  Decrease the size of the free page
         cache by a factor of two.

 The default number of free pages cached is 64.
```

Hence, the symbolic link you create at `/etc/malloc.conf` enables guard page, and reduces the cache size by a factor of 4, presumably from 64 pages to 16 pages.

If you just want to enable guard pages without modifying the cache size, just

```
# ln -s G /etc/malloc.conf
```

Comment: why do they modify the cache size? does it helps regarding security? Thanks!!

Comment: so I missed that in the man pages, thanks, but how can I get the status of the malloc conf? only by testing? with what? paxtest?

Comment: use `ls -l /etc/malloc.conf` to see the current setting, or `rm /etc/malloc.conf` to remove it.  To *verify* behaviour, I'd probably write a quick-and-dirty test to malloc various size blocks and read/write at various offsets beyond the returned block.